# Generating random variates from the following pdf

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, density-function

I'm working through some example of probability distributions and I'm struggling to derive the formula for the following pdf

$f(x) = \frac{1}{0.02}e^{-\left\lvert x \right\rvert/0.01}$

My undersanding is that I would need to integrate the pdf between 0 and x to derive the cdf and then invert the cdf to get the formula I am after. I am having trouble doing the integration to get the cdf as I have never come across a pdf with an absolute value in it.

Answer (score 5):

This is [laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), you can either use the CDF given in the wikipedia page or find a proof. If you want to integrate it yourself, the integral will be from $-\infty$ (not $0$) to $x$, and for the negative portion, you'll just substitute $|x|=-x$ and do the integration.

Answer (score 1):

For actually generating $n$ such values, here are three approaches in R turning uniform pseudo-random variables into your distribution.  The first is a simplified inversion of the CDF, putting its two parts together; the second essentially takes an exponential distribution and applies a random sign; and the third is essentially the difference between two exponential distributions

```
n <- 1000
rate <- 0.01 

U1 <- runif(n)
U2 <- runif(n)

Xa <- (1/rate) * log(abs(2*U1-1)) * (2*U1-1) / abs(2*U1-1)

Xb <- (1/rate) * log(U1) * (2*(U2 > 1/2) - 1)

Xc <- (1/rate) * log(U1) - (1/rate) * log(U2)
```

Comment: +1. There are plenty of other methods available in `R`, ranging from using normal variates (`x <- rnorm(n);
y <- rnorm(n);
X <- sign(x) * (x^2+y^2) * rate/2`) to Poisson processes (`X <- rate * n * diff(sort(U1)) * sign(diff(U1))`) to direct use of `rgamma` or `rchisq`.